# SVN icons not showing next to folders after project checkout through TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn

I am trying to checkout the complete project from Tortoise SVN. After the checkout the folder suppose to have green mark on it. But I am not able to get that.

Comment: Please add the commands which you have used to checkout the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may try refreshing the view with F5 for the status icons to show up. You can also restart the computer if you've recently installed TortoiseSVN, but did not reboot the computer after the installation. Read the FAQ: https://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlnotshowing